# Styles working locally but not applied properly when running `npm run build` on react app with tailwindcss

Tags: css, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, tailwind-css

I'm trying to figure out what exactly is happening, but I'm all out of ideas. I've recently transitioned to Tailwind and I set it up according to instructions for create-react-app, which can be seen [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app).

I've also tried another setup, but I got the same problem. That setup can be seen [here](https://rfitz.io/blog/tailwind-with-react/).

For whatever reason, everything is working normally in local development (when running code with `npm start`). But when I build the code, I'm getting some really weird stylings.

[image: This is in local development]
This is in local development

[image: This is when npm run build is run]
This is when `npm run build` is run.

Specific part of the code which isn't displaying as it should:

```js
 <div className='w-full lg:w-1/4 m-auto p-5 text-center lg:shadow-2xl rounded-xl'>
      <HelmetComponent
        title='Log in | Notify Me'
        description='Login page for Notify Me.'
      />
      <NavbarLoggedOut/>
      <h1 className='font-bold'>Log in</h1>

      <LoginForm
        onSubmit={onLogin}
      />

      <div className='text-base mt-2'>
        <p>
          Don&#39;t have an account? <LinkButton onClick={() => history.push('/signup')} label='Sign up here!' />
        </p>
      </div>

      <div className='mt-4'>
        <GoogleOAuthComponent
          buttonText='Log in with Google'
          setErrorMessage={updateErrorMessage}
        />
      </div>

      <div className='mt-4'>
        <LoadingBar
          isLoading={waitingForServerResponse}
        />
      </div>

      <div>
        {displayInfoMessage()}
      </div>
    </div>
```

I've opened both files with inspect element, and everything seems to be the same. And problem is everywhere where there is any kind of `h1` element as far as I saw.

This is my `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  important: true,
  purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './public/index.html'],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    colors: {
      transparent: 'transparent',
      current: 'currentColor',
      main: {
        light: '#508991',
        DEFAULT: '#1b262c',
        '100': '#DBF9F4',
        '700': '#60949B',
      },
      black: colors.black,
      white: colors.white,
      gray: colors.trueGray,
      indigo: colors.indigo,
      red: colors.rose,
      yellow: colors.amber,
      blue: colors.blue,
      green: colors.green,
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

I've also tried setting `purge: false` to see if that was causing the problem, but it didn't change anything.

If anyone has any kind of idea what could be causing this, I'd appreciate it.

EDIT: I've also noticed that the padding differs on development and build, so if anyone has any idea why that's happening, that would be also nice.

FINAL EDIT: Problem was in the leftover boostrap files, since the project used that before switching to tailwind. In development environment bootstrap css was loaded on top of everything else, which lead to strange behavior.

There was leftover import in the `index.tsx`: `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'`

After that import was removed, and `boostrap` package was removed from `package.json` file and `node_modules` folder was deleted and packages were reinstalled problem disappeared. True layout was actually generated by `npm run build`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was in the leftover boostrap files, since the project used that before switching to tailwind. In development environment bootstrap css was loaded on top of everything else, which lead to strange behavior.

There was leftover import in the `index.tsx`: `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'`

After that import was removed, and `boostrap` package was removed from `package.json` file and `node_modules` folder was deleted and packages were reinstalled problem disappeared. True layout was actually generated by `npm run build`

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind resets all headings to have the base font size (16px by default) so unless you are explicit, that’s what you get. That means you’re actually getting extra styling in development that isn’t supposed to be there unless you have custom styles somewhere.

Add `text-xl` Or whatever size you want it to be to the `h1`

Comment: Do you have an idea how to disable extra styling in development, my guess is always going with `text-{size}` classes instead of headings? 

Also, I've noticed that the padding also slightly differs in development and in production. Do you have any idea why that's the case?